# Set EventCallback<string> outside of a Blazor component?

Tags: c#, blazor

I am building a Blazor ProgressBar demo, and I am attempting to move some code out of my Blazor component into a C# class called ProgressManager. This is so I can abstract the code and make the ProgressManager a `CascadingParameter` to the ProgressBar component.

I know how to set an `EventCallback` parameter for a component like this:

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> UpdateNotification { get; set; }
```

What I don't know how to do is set this same type of property on a C# class.

I have this code in my Start method:

```
public void ShowProgressSimulation()
{
    // Create a ProgressManager
    this.ProgressManager = new ProgressManager();
    this.ProgressManager.UpdateNotification = Refresh;
    this.ProgressManager.Start();
    
    // Refresh the UI
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

The part that does not work is:
`this.ProgressManager.UpdateNotification = Refresh;`

The error is:

> Cannot convert method group 'Refresh' to non-delegate type 'EventCallback'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

I also tried:
`this.ProgressManager.UpdateNotification += Refresh;`

And this leads to "EventCallback cannot be applied to method group" (paraphrasing).

Comment: I solved my issue, but I didn't answer this question, so I am going to leave the question up just in case anyone can answer so I know.

My issue was I needed a way to get notifications when the value of a Progress Bar changes, so I can update the UI.

I solved my issue just by creating an Interface with 1 method, Refresh.
Then when I create my ProgressManager, I set my Blazor page as the Subscriber (it could easily be a list if needed):

this.ProgressManager = new ProgressManager();               this.ProgressManager.Subcriber = this;

Comment: Is there a trick to getting code in a comment to be in line format and not wrap everything like it is a paragraph? The above message was typed with many line breaks.

Comment: Note: EventCallback is a struct that was invented to alter the Target of an event. It is not a delegate type.

I don't think you should make the "ProgressManager a cascadingparameter to the ProgressBar component." I'd suggest you to make ProgressManager a service which can be injected into components that use the ProgressBar component, controlling and providing it with state management and other functionalities in prospect.

Comment: Note also that exposing the ProgressManager as a cascadingparameter will require you to define a class that exposes it so.
[Here's a link to][1] code which define a service named NewsProvider with events that are handled by components. You may need something similar. The main point is that you do not create event or event call backs using the EventCallback 'delegate'


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496040/is-it-safe-to-call-statehaschanged-from-an-arbitrary-thread

Comment: Thank you, I already got rid of the ProgressManager and just moved my timer to the ProgressBar component itself.

Comment: @DataJuggler Do not post a possible answer in comments. Post it as an answer and then you can benefit from full formatting features and users can also vote for it, share it etc.

Comment: Thanks ViRuSTriNiTy (if I spelled that right).

Answer (score 29):

Turns out you can assign an event callback from C# code like this:

```cs
this.ProgressManager.UpdateNotification = new EventCallback(this, (Action)Refresh);

void Refresh() {}
```

It also works with async methods, e.g.:

```cs
this.ProgressManager.UpdateNotification = new EventCallback(this, (Func<ValueTask>)RefreshAsync);

ValueTask RefreshAsync() {}
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use [EventCallbackFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallbackfactory?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to more conveniently create event callback objects, e.g.:

```cs
new EventCallbackFactory().Create(this, Refresh)
```

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the following code to create an `EventCallBack` though the factory without having to new up the `EventCallbackFactory`

```
Button.Clicked = EventCallback.Factory.Create( this, ClickHandler );
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to toggle the handler on and off and check the .HasDelegate status, and also pass a parameter (of type Item) to the delegate, this is what worked for me:

```
private void toggleHandler()
{
    if (isRowClickHandler)
    { // remove handler
        myGrid.OnRowClick = new EventCallback<Item>(null, null); 
        // EventCallback<Item>.Empty didn't work, OnRowClick.HasDelegate still returned true
    }
    else
    { // add handler
        myGrid.OnRowClick = new EventCallback<Item>(myGrid, (Action<Item>)handleRowClick);
    }
    isRowClickHandler = !isRowClickHandler;
}

private void handleRowClick(Item item)
{
    App.ShowNotification(Status.Success, $"Click invoked on row with value {item.Value1}");
}
```